# stdout message shows "Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied" as log

Tags: asp.net-core

I have hosted .net core application on IIS. When i am trying to browse the application, **HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure** error comes up on browser. On checking stdout logs of application, i found that error message is "**Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile**' is denied"

I am trying to host this application on my local IIS.

Comment: you should update your question with information about how you configured your application pool, what user does it run as, is it configured to load a profile?

Comment: What is your .net core version? Is there any issue with hosting built-in asp.net core template? For this error, try to grant `IIS_IUSRS` Read/Write access to: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile'

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. @TaoZhou isn't it risky to give IIS access to systemprofile folder? .net core version is 2.0.

Comment: Hi @JoeAudette, thanks for showing interest in this question. I followed below steps for deployment.

Comment: Link which i followed for steps of deployment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/publish-asp-net-core-2-0-application-on-iis/ 
I followed below steps for deployment. 1) Right clicked on project. 2) Clicked on Publish option. 3) Created a folder profile and gave path of inetpub-->wwwroot folder's path to created deployable folder there. 4) Then in IIS, created site for the application which is pointing to this folder. 5) Set CLR version of application pool for this site as "No Managed Code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes because of required .net core version not installed on server. One has to be careful about version number (eg. 3.1) and then also about whether its  hosting bundle or sdk or runtime. In my opinion, hosting bundle is needed when using IIS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).